# How to create a command block with alarm sounds

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a prison map I am building, but need a command block that sounds like an alarm.
Problem is, the command block starts getting choppy after repeating continuosly.

Anybody have suggestions for an alarm type sounding command block

OS: XBOX1, SERIES S. Bedrock edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remixing different sounds in Minecraft really comes down to experience and trial & Error.

Here is what I use for alarm.

```
playsound block.anvil.land ambient @a ^ ^1 ^1 1 2
```

The choppy issue is nothing to do with commands and the game itself. I would suggest for you to use a datapack instead, so that you could limit the frequency of the sound with scoreboards easily.

Comment: Throwing this in a command block didn't seem to work, it's malformed. Is this for XBOX/Bedrock ED?

Comment: Also, I need the audio to be able to be heard from a large portion of the map from one singular block using this sound.

Comment: Hi, I overlooked the fact that you are a bedrock player so there is a discrepancy between syntax. According to the MC wiki https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands/playsound
You can fill in the parameters accordingly. Sorry since I really don't play bedrock.

Comment: As for the second one, augmenting the minVolume to a high value such as 10, would allow the sound to be heard all over the map

Comment: TYSM, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Also, thanks to bedrock you can set the repeating commandblock that runs this to have a built-in delay, playing the sound every few ticks instead of every tick.

Answer (score -1):

I like to use

```
/execute if score alarm animglobal matches 1 run playsound minecraft:block.note_block.flute ambient @a ~ ~ ~ 5 0.5

/execute if score alarm animglobal matches 1 run playsound minecraft:block.note_block.flute ambient @a ~ ~ ~ 5 0.54
```

Then I put a clock that sets "alarm" to one and zero so I can scatter the command block pairs around. The two sounds clash with each other so it gives a bad sound, though it still sounds like a normal alarm. You don't have to use the objective animglobal I just ripped the commands from my world.

Comment: This answer is for the wrong edition of the game.